# window.onerror & catching MULTIPLE errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling

Is this possible? I have a handler which keeps appending string info to a string everytime an error hits and then on window unload I want to send this info via AJAX to the server,

but once an error has been handled it seems to not be able to process another, is this just because they are fatal errors? Or am I missing something?

```
ErrorManager: (function () {
        function Init(message) {
            InitErrorHandler();
            InitAjaxHandler();
        }
        function InitErrorHandler() {
            Data.ErrorHandlerText = "";
            Data.ErrorHandlerCount = 0;
            window.onerror = function(errorMessage, url, line) {
                Data.ErrorHandlerText += ("Error: "+(Data.ErrorHandlerCount+1)+" \n\n");
                //Get error specific info
                Data.ErrorHandlerText += escape(errorMessage) + "\n";
                Data.ErrorHandlerText +=  escape(url) + "\n";
                Data.ErrorHandlerText +=  escape(line) + "\n";
                Data.ErrorHandlerCount++;
                return true;
            }
        }
        function InitAjaxHandler() {
            window.onbeforeunload = function() { //when browser closed
                Data.ErrorHandlerCount > 0 && SendErrorsToAjax();
            }
        }
        function SendErrorsToAjax() {
            PrepareErrorsForAjax();
            //$.getJSON(Interface.Utility.PrefixURL('/emailjserrors/'+Data.ErrorHandlerText), AjaxCallback);
        }
        function AjaxCallback(response) {
        }
        function PrepareErrorsForAjax() {
            var preText = "A user has encountered a few errors: \n\n";
            //Get session info
            var userAgent, activePageID, accountNO, consumerNO;
            userAgent = escape(navigator.userAgent);
            preText += "User agent: "+userAgent+" \n";
            if($.mobile.activePage != null) {
                activePageID = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
                preText += "Page ID: "+activePageID+" \n";
            }
            //Get info that may or may not be set

            if(Data.authJSON != null && Data.authJSON.consumer != null) {
                preText += "Account Number: " +Data.authJSON.consumer.accountNo+" \n";
                preText += "Consumer Number: "+ Data.authJSON.consumer.consumerNO+" \n";
            }
            preText += "\n The following errors were encountered:\n\n";
            Data.ErrorHandlerText = preText + Data.ErrorHandlerText;
        }
        return {
            Init: Init,
            SendErrorsToAjax: SendErrorsToAjax
        }
    })(),
```

Answer (score 0):

If an error happens, execution stops, and window.onerror **might** be called (it is not guaranteed for all errors).

If an error happens but is caught by a try-catch, the function you set in window.onerror **won't** be called.

If an error happens in the error handling code...:)

onbeforeunload is not a good bet. It might not even execute your code. It is used to display a text to the user, and has different restrictions across browsers.